# Finding local maximum between two peak or points using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

[image: intensity plot]

I have intensity points which is marked as pink in above plot, and these are stored in variable and is given as

```
intensity_info =[ 35.9349
   46.4465
   46.4790
   45.7496
   44.7496
   43.4790
   42.5430
   41.4351
   40.1829
   37.4114
   33.2724
   29.5447
   26.8373
   24.8171
   24.2724
   24.2487
   23.5228
   23.5228
   24.2048
   23.7057
   22.5228
   22.0000
   21.5210
   20.7294
   20.5430
   20.2504
   20.2943
   21.0219
   22.0000
   23.1096
   25.2961
   29.3364
   33.4351
   37.4991
   40.8904
   43.2706
   44.9798
   47.4553
   48.9324
   48.6855
   48.5210
   47.9781
   47.2285
   45.5342
   34.2310 ];
```

I also have information of point A, B and C which is calculated by :

```
  [maxtab, mintab] = peakdet(intensity_info, 1); % maxtab has A and B information and 
                                                  % mintab has C information
```

peakdet.m matlab code can be found here: (http://www.billauer.co.il/peakdet.html). I want to calculate point D (where there is sight increase in intensity value i.e. if we come down from point A intensity decreases but at point D there is slight increase in intensity). As  seen from graph below point C can also lie in the left of point D and in this case if we come down from point B intensity decrease and at D there is slight increase in intensity. Intensity values for below graph below is given as:

```
intensity_info =[29.3424
   39.4847
   43.7934
   47.4333
   49.9123
   51.4772
   52.1189
   51.6601
   48.8904
   45.0000
   40.9561
   36.5868
   32.5904
   31.0439
   29.9982
   27.9579
   26.6965
   26.7312
   28.5631
   29.3912
   29.7496
   29.7715
   29.7294
   30.2706
   30.1847
   29.7715
   29.2943
   29.5667
   31.0877
   33.5228
   36.7496
   39.7496
   42.5009
   45.7934
   49.1847
   52.2048
   53.9123
   54.7276
   54.9781
   55.0000
   54.9781
   54.7276
   53.9342
   51.4246
   38.2512];
```

and Point A ,B and C calculated in same manner as above.

How can I calculate point D in these cases?

[image: Intensity plot 2 with C on left of D point]

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Are you just looking for any local maximum between A and B?

Comment: @Oli: I think he wants the maximum deflection between the data and a curve (perhaps parabola or raised cosine) passing through A-C-B.

Comment: @Oli:  yes I want local maxima between A & B point

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Can You help in finding local maxima between Point A and B ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the alternative solution. The extrema.m helped in finding Point D in above two garphs. The extrema.m  can be downloaded from (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12275-extrema-m-extrema2-m) and used in following way to find point D:

```
 [ymax,imax,ymin,imin] = extrema(intensity_info);
 figure;plot(x,intensity_info,x(imax),ymax,'g.',x(imin),ymin,'r.');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not MATLAB literate, but if the 'tabs' are subtables, then perhaps you can manipulate them to create other subtables... something like (I repeat, illiterate)

```
left_of_graph = part of graph from A to C
right_of_graph = part of graph from C to B

left_delta = some fraction of the difference between A's y-value and C's y-value
right_delta = some fraction of the difference between C's y-value and B's y-value

[left_maxtab,left_mintab] = peakdet(left_of_graph,left_delta)
[right_maxtab,right_mintab] = peakdet(right_of_graph,right_delta)
```

I *do* have some experience with peak analysis, so I will say this will help, not answer, the problem.  You can find all the peaks you want, but that doesn't mean the data is worth squinting at.  Noise and imperfect resolution are real.  Happy hunting!

PS You might also scan for all points higher than both neighbors in the whole band.  That is gauranteed to miss none of the 'true' maxima, but to give you more 'false' maxima than you can count (although your data looks pretty smooth!).

Comment: I did not understand your concept of left_delta and right_delta. Can you please elaborate what exactly you want to say.. ......Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution your looking for is a numerical method based on iterations,in your particular case bisection is the one who best suits cause others like uniform sequential search do not take an interval as an input.
This is the implementation for bisection:

```
    function [ a, b, L ] = Bisection( f, a, b, e, d )
%[a,b] is the interval for your local maxima; e is the error for the result and d is the step(dx).

L = b - a;
while(L > e)
  xa = ((a + b)/2) - d/2;
  xb = ((a + b)/2) + d/2;

  ya = subs(f,xa);
  yb = subs(f,xb);

  if(ya < yb) 
      a = xa;
  else
      b = xb;
  end
  L = b - a;    
end
end
```

The method before is pretty efficient and straightforward to use, although there are others even better(in performance) like Fibonacci and Gold Section methods.

Cheers.

Comment: @ Daniel: Thanks for your reply. Can you pls. tell me what if 'f' ?

Comment: f is the symbolic expression for your function

Comment: If you don't have the function you probably may wanna go for aproximating it with lagrange or newton interpolation.